# how to insert special characters in oracle query

Tags: oracle, air, quotes

Bringing data from sql to oracle, I need to  generate a query from Oracle where I am sending a query to sql to replace “ in a text field.

So, in sql I want to generate a query in oracle "`SELECT REPLACE(TEXT, '“', '"')`. It works fine if i run this directly on SQL server. But, since I need to store this query in Oracle first and then read it, oracle converts it to a junk "`SELECT REPLACE(TEXT, '<somejunk>, '"')`. Does anyone know how to make oracle literally take “. I tried ESCAPE and \ but nothing works

Comment: "some junk" isn't terribly helpful. However, this sounds like a character set issue - check your database character set and your operating system and client character set/encoding, both for your insert and query. Oracle maybe storing the correct character and your client can't display it, for example.

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatenate two single quotes.

```
SELECT REPLACE( '"" - Double quotes to single quotes ', '""', ''''||'''') from dual;
```

Comment: The question seems to be about replacing 'curly quotes' or 'smart quotes' - i.e. `“` - with straight double quotes - `"` - rather than dealing with single quotes in a string literal.